# Hide post on homepage using tag id

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My WordPress website theme is Magsy. It has the latest blog list as a slider. I wanted to hide a post that contains an alert tag. how to hide specific posts in the latest post using tag id? Please help me.

```
   function wpb_exclude_from_home($query) {
      if ($query->is_home() ) {
          $query->set('post__not_in', array(42));
      }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpb_exclude_from_home');
```

Comment: I am new to WordPress backend. I took reference from https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-hide-a-post-from-home-page-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function wpb_exclude_from_home($query) {
      if ($query->is_home()) {
          $query->set('cat', '-42');
      }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpb_exclude_from_home');
```

You check in home page like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
   );

   $query = new WP_Query($args);
   
   echo '<pre>';
   echo print_r($query);
   echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: for post tag should I write tag instead of cat?

Comment: Hey Sobir, I tried this code but it is not working in latest posts list.

Comment: Did you add this `$query->is_main_query()` in your `if` statement?

Comment: I edited my answer. Check again. I checked it and it works me fine

Comment: thank you. yes, it is working with categories. but what if I want to hide post using a specific post tag? if it possible?

Comment: Use this `$query->set('tag__not_in' => array( 37, 47 ));`// Display posts that do not have any of the two tag ids 37 and 47.

Comment: I tried this. but this is giving an error,  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Sorry for mistake.  I checked it and use this `$query->set('tag__not_in', array(6));` and it works fine as you wanted

Comment: hey, thank you so much. it is working as I wanted. I have learned so much from you. thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped